# from Java to Groovy : how to handle "String myArray[]"

Tags: java, arrays, groovy

I tried to to compile Java files using groovyc command.  When it hits

> public static void main(String myArray[])

that is in Java file, the compiler says:

unexpected token: [ @line xxxxx

how could I handle this situation in general - these might be a lot of cases in Java files?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simply

```
 public static void main(String[] myArray)
```

or (more groovy)

```
static main(myArray)
```

Comment: You can actually usually get away with `static main( args )`